# Codeigniter autosearch using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

ajax call is not gt in to the controller   when i echo out
  ===========Ajax auto complete search ========================

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$(".search").keyup(function() 
{ 
var searchid = $(this).val();
//var dataString = 'search='+ searchid;
if(searchid!='')

{
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url()."/search/search"?>",
    data: {searchid:searchid}
    cache: false,
    success: function(html)
    {
        alert(html);
    $("#result ").html(html).show();
    }
    });
}return false;    
});

$("#result ").live("click",function(e){ 
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    var $name = $clicked.find('.name').html();
    var decoded = $("<div/>").html($name).text();
    $('#searchid').val(decoded);
});
$(document).live("click", function(e) { 
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    if (! $clicked.hasClass("search")){
    $("#result").fadeOut(); 
    }
});
$('#searchid').click(function(){
    $("#result").fadeIn();
});
});

</script>
```

=============================Controller=========================

```
public function search()
{
    //$q = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search']);
    //echo"helloooo".$q;
    //die();
      $searchid=$this->input->post('searchid');
      echo "aaaaaaa".$searchid;
      die();
        //echo "name".$name;
        //die();
       $data=$this->search_model->autocomplete($q);        
       // print_r($data);
    }  

}
```

=============================Model=================================

```
public function autocomplete($q)
{
     $this->db->select('uid', 'name');
       $this->db->from('tbl_reg');
       // $this->db->where('suppress', 0);
        $this->db->like('name', $q,'both' );
        $this->db->order_by("name", "asc");

        $query = $this->db->get();

        //echo "query".$query;
        //die();


        //  $query=$this->db->query("select *  from  tbl_reg where name='$name' ");

        /**  
          $whereCondition = array('name' =>$search);
        $this->db->where($whereCondition);
        $this->db->from('tbl_reg');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
          **/



        if($query->num_rows()>0)
    {


    foreach($query->result() as $row)
        {
          $data[] = $row;
        }

        //echo "query".$query;
        //die();
       // foreach($query->result_array() as $row){

          //  $data[] = $row;
       // }
        //return $data;
        return $query;
    }  
 }
 }
```

Comment: It's usually a good idea to explain your problem and some things you've tried rather than to post all your code.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

View

```
<link rel="stylesheet"href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/themes/base/minified/jquery-ui.min.css" type="text/css" /> 

  //Also include this script file
 //http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js

$(function () {

    //autocomplete
    $(".auto").autocomplete({
       source: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>search/auto_search",
        minLength: 1
    });

});

<input name="" id="" type="text" class="auto"/>
```

=============Controller ============

```
public function auto_search() {
    if (isset($_GET['term'])) {
        $data = $this->Search_model->autocomplete(urldecode($_GET['term']));
        $json_array = array();
        foreach ($data as $row)
            array_push($json_array, $row->name);
        echo json_encode($json_array);
    }
}
```

===================Model==================

```
public function autocomplete($like) {

    $this->db->select('name');
    $this->db->from('tbl_reg');
   // $this->db->where('suppress', 0);
    $this->db->like('name', $like );
    $this->db->order_by("name", "asc");
    $q = $this->db->get();
    if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $q->result();
    }
}
```

Hope you're looking for this,let us know the result.

Comment: i got an error  like this.. what is the problem with ths?  wll you provide solution for this???

Comment: i got an error  like this.. what is the problem with ths?  wll you provide solution for this???Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'status' in 'where clause'

SELECT `name` FROM (`tbl_reg`) WHERE `status` = 'ACTIVE' AND `name` LIKE '%%'

Comment: Please use the edited code and try again.. You need to make sure the table name and the field names are according to your database. Let me know the result.

Comment: You must pass an argument to the function autocomplete().
Like $data = $this->Search_model->autocomplete($like);

Answer (score 0):

You made a controller with name `search` i.e your class name is `Search` and calling a function with name `search`. If you made any function with class name it will be your constructor. So suggest you to change your method name `search` to anything else.